# Does "differ by" even exist?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, expressions, prepositions

I have a question about the preposition for *differ* in the following context:

> A differs B merely **from** a chemical element.

Or better to say:

> A differs B **by** a chemical element.

I will prefer the first one to the second one, because I cannot find a reliable source for the meaning of *differ by*.

Comment: They convey  different meanings: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=differ+from%2C+differ+by&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdiffer%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdiffer%20by%3B%2Cc0. Differ *from* something, differ *by* (an amount, a size), "Their means differ by about $200, or more than 10 percent".

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to clarify the difference to find a suitable expression. Are A and B molecules? What meaning should your sentence convey? Does A have one more/less atom then B, is one atom substituted by a different element? The purpose of your sentence is not quite clear.

Comment: And to add to the comment of @Josh61; Differ _in_ something: "My brother and I differ in the way we dress."

Comment: @inVader A and B are both molecules and they have the same structure, except that B has one atom substituted by another element. My purpose is to describe the only difference between the two molecules.

Comment: Your given usage, "A differs B", does not even exist, so any other questions about constructions using it are moot.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*Differs By* is certainly applicable, but not in a way you think it to be, eg-

> A differs from B *by* a certain amount.

or

> X differs Y *by* 10.

So a more natural sentence construction in your case would be like :

> A differs **from** B **by** a chemical element.

Both the sentences that you mentioned are also grammatically correct, but the above is simply how I would like to put it, and how it seemed the most natural to me.

Comment: I have never seen a construction of the form 'X differs Y by 10', and none of the 6 online dictionaries I have checked in license a transitive usage.